# How to make extension after editing

Tags: joomla

I have downloaded a joomla extension it is in MVC format.

I have edited it and now I want it to become an extension again the updated form which I have created. How is this possible it is currently running on website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify an existing extension, just download the file(s) you need to modify, edit them, and upload them again in the same place. There's no need to create a new extension package.

If you want to **duplicate** the extension, i.e. to create another one from the modified files, that's definitely more complex and I suggest to start from here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component